# How to specify the location to place static files in django project?

Tags: python-3.x, django, routes, django-settings

After you create your first project with `django-admin startproject mysite` you get a directory that looks like this:

```
mysite/
    manage.py       - script for running tasks
    mysite/
        __init__.py
        settings.py - for general setting configuration
        urls.py     - for routing configuration
        wsgi.py     - for webserver configuration
```

What I want is 3 directories for me to put various files that are usable across all django apps.

```
mysite/
    manage.py       
    javascript_css/
        ...
    html_templates/
        ...
    custom_modules/
        ...
    mysite/
        __init__.py
        settings.py 
        urls.py     
        wsgi.py
```

What settings would I need to change in `settings.py` in order to configure this behaviour and how would I reference the javascript_css/html_templates/custom_modules in my django apps?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find everything in the django docs:

1. [static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/)
2. [html templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/templates/#configuration)

And it's probably better to keep folder named as `static` and `templates`, it's more readable.